# How to make host only mode work in VM

Tags: windows-xp, networking, virtual-machine

I'm running Windows inside a VM inside OSX. If I set the connection to host only, then I get a connection that seems to work. However, when I go try to go to web pages, they won't load. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint is in the name of the connection type... **"Host Only"**

It means what it says - create a virtual network between the *Virtual Machine* and the *Host Virtualbox is running on*

To get outside the local host you will either need to use *NAT* mode or *Bridged*

Comment: I'm just going to outside sites like normal. Not using a proxy.

Comment: What if I want to use host only mode? What changes should I make to OSX? Which program is useful?

Comment: Then you would need to turn on ip forwarding (not sure how in OS/X, but if it's like FreeBSD then `sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1` should do it until the next reboot) and add a static route to your router to the private host-only network routed through your OS/X machine's IP address (how depends on your router).

Comment: @Jedi Why do you want to use host-only? Sounds like NAT is the mode you really want.